# Ajax call to controller method not passing parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am trying to make an AJax call to a controller method the parameter is null no matter what I try.  I have followed all the similar SO posts but to no avail. Sorry if the answer is there, I cant find it.  The code I have is...

**Ajax Call**

```
    var sguid = $(nTr).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
    url: "/Dashboard/Reporting/GetBlacklistedSoftwareItems",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({guid: sguid}),
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
    alert("page not found");
        }
    },
    success: function (data) {
    //DO Something
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

**Controller Method**

```
public JsonResult GetBlacklistedSoftwareItems(string guid)
{
    List<DeviceSoftware> ldevice = new List<DeviceSoftware>();
    Guid i = Guid.Parse(guid);
    ReportMethods reportingMethods = new ReportMethods();
    ldevice = reportingMethods.GetNonCompliantApplicationReport(CompanyId);

    DeviceSoftware ds = ldevice.Find(x => x.Device.Guid == i);
    List<DeviceApplication> da = new List<DeviceApplication>();
    if (ds != null)
    {
        da = ds.DeviceApplications;
    }

    return Json(da, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The method is being hit its just `guid` is alway `null`.  `sguid` does hold the data I am trying to pass. 
Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: In your $.Ajax() call add contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" , then it will bre resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Against everything I read I changed

`data: JSON.stringify({guid: sguid}),`

To

`data: {guid: sguid},`

Now working.

Answer (score 0):

Fred,

You need to make GetBlacklistedSoftwareItems a post method....

try this...

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetBlacklistedSoftwareItems(string guid)
{

Answer (score 0):

Small changes needs to be done.

```
var sguid = $(nTr).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
    url: "/Dashboard/Reporting/GetBlacklistedSoftwareItems",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" ,//This is very important 
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    Data: JSON. stringify ({guild: squid}),
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
    alert("page not found");
        }
    },
    success: function (data) {
    //DO Something
    },
error: function () {
    alert("error");
}
```

});

Add the ***contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" ,*** to the $.Ajax  Call.
:)